# Xcode 6 with iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9

I'm fairly new to iOS development and I upgraded my device to iOS 9.0 beta, to see how my app faired. However, I did not upgrade to Xcode 7 beta. I'm getting an error that says my device is now "ineligible", specifically,

> iPhone (3) may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.

Is this standard? Do I have to upgrade to Xcode 7 if I'm running iOS 9.0?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you need to install Xcode 7 in order to develop for iOS 9. You are able to keep Xcode 6 running alongside Xcode 7.

Comment: ah crap thats a bummer- I can't get Xcode 7 to even launch. I guess its a downgrade then. Thanks so much for the help + quick answer.

Comment: This is not correct, and for those of us trying to ship before XCode7 is out of Beta and support iOS9, it is not an option. You can debug swift 1.2 on iOS9 devices - you just have to launch XCode7 once with your iOS9 device attached as outlined in Hassan's answer.

Comment: @David Have you supported a new major version of iOS before? Xcode 7 will go into Gold Master. You will be able to submit your iOS 9 apps through the Gold Master release, which comes out before iOS 9 is released. So yes, this is correct. Yes there are workarounds, but if you're developing for iOS 9 you should be doing it in Xcode 7.

Comment: Hi Ben - yes I am aware of that. Updating our codebase to Swift2 is not realistic for our shipping deadline. We need to ship before Swift2/XCode7 is at Gold Master, but we'd like to make sure it works on iOS9.

Comment: @BenKane - I was wrong to state your answer was incorrect. Your answer is correct, as is Hassan's. They are just answering slightly different questions :). I cannot edit my first response now, however.

Comment: Ah, so your problem is the Swift 1.2 to 2.0 conversion and still needing to do releases before the GM. Well, I guess you will have to use the workaround. I don't agree that that makes this answer wrong. That situation is most likely only one that will apply this year. I wouldn't expect game breaking changes in Swift next year. Just like if your app was written in Obj-C it wouldn't be an issue. What you should have is a Swift 2 branch for your project that has the Swift 2 code, while your main development is still Swift 1.2, then merge when the time comes. But maybe that isn't realistic either.

Comment: @David I agree, they are both correct in different situations. Thanks for that acknowledgment. I answered the question from a pretty general perspective, since OP didn't mention a Swift constraint.

Comment: this is not the answer OP was expecting, there are ways to debug on iOS 9 devices by copying over DeviceSupport files from newer Xcode version.

Answer (score 30):

The problem with Xcode 7 is that it wants to change your swift code to be able to run. There is way here. Download Xcode 7 and run it. After a few minutes with some installations, connect your iOS 9 device to computer so you can see it in Xcode 7. Then quit Xcode 7 and run Xcode 6 and surprisingly, Xcode 6 will detect your device and you can run your app on it.

Comment: This must be the trick I was doing... somehow was able to get mine working with XCode 6.  I removed XCode 7 and now it's stopped working... guess I need to do this.

Comment: This is best temporary fix until XCode 7 is ready and you're not ready to convert to swift 2.

Comment: You may have to go to Product > Clean to get your build to work in XCode 6 if you receive the `swiftc` error.

Comment: I think this should be the right answer. Because even needing Xcode 7, you can still run your code in an iOS 9 device from Xcode 6. @ABC

Comment: Agreed - this is the correct answer, and a life-saver. Thank you Hassan

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Still working with iOS 9.3.2 and Xcode 6.4. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11):

**You can RUN App on iOS 9 device using Xcode 6,** But firstly you need to **build your app on XCode 7, after that it will support on XCode 6.** I have checked this on My Mac.

**Steps**

**Build the project on Xcode 7 while Xcode 6 is opened on the same project.
Disconnect the device and reconnect it.**(Now u can run ur app on XCode6, It may take little time to load device)

When i have checked iOS9 with Xcode6, Bugs are very less. So i have plan to support iOS9 with XCode6 for quick release. Later i will do for XCode7.

Comment: How do I reverse this as I would like to submit a new build to the iOS App Store? I currently cannot because it says it has been built with a beta version of Xcode (Xcode 7) even though I have cleaned and built it in most recently on Xcode 6 (I also unistalled Xcode 7).

Comment: I just did this and wanted to post about it but I used the search and realized someone was faster :/

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to debug devices with iOS 9 installed with Xcode 6. 
Go to Xcode main menu: Product -> Destination and select your device. Even though it says your device is ineligible, you can still select it and then it usually works.

If it doesn't work, try to run Xcode 7 and wait while it indexes the device with iOS 9. Sometimes you need to unplug and plug the device again.

Comment: Hm, your method of product->destination was actually what was causing the error for me. As for Xcode 7, it was actually so unstable for me that it wouldn't launch at all. Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: Usually, the device is selected through the Xcode Toolbar -> "Set the active scheme". And Xcode doesn't allow to select ineligible device there. That's why I added my answer. Did you try to install Xcode 7 beta and allows it to index your device and only then run Xcode 6? I tried this on different Macs and it works for all of them, but sometimes it requires to plug/unplug the device.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work at all for me... It still says Ineligible in the Product Destination menu... and still throws the error when I go to build it.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy.

1. Download Xcode 7 or 7.1
2. In finder Browse within both Xcode apps to following directory. 
   `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
3. Copy 9.0 and 9.1 folders over to Xcode 6 in same directory.
4. Restart Xcode and reconnect your iOS 9 device.

## Kaboom

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ben you need to download XCode7 which release date now is right on the corner (mid-sept) but you DON'T need to build your application under XCode7. The trick is to let XCode7 copy symbols. Once done you can build your app on your device under XCode 6.4 and without to support Swift 2.0: your device will be recognized then. So yes you will need to keep a copy of XCode 6 and XCode 7 for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xcode 7 in order to develop for iOS 9. You are able to keep Xcode 6 running alongside Xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy workaround -- especially if you have access to Xcode 7 on a different machine (but you can do it on the same mac too):

Deploy any app, e.g. Apple sample code, from Xcode 7 once.  Then go back to Xcode 6.4 and it will no longer consider the device "ineligible."