# iOS 9 not supported on Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

I downloaded the iOS 9 beta for the iPhone 5s and wanted to test an application that I have finished but now it says that my iPhone is an ineligible device. Is there a way I can still run apps on my iPhone without downloading the Xcode 7 beta?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 with iOS 9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823478/xcode-6-with-ios-9)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you installed iOS 9 beta onto your iPhone, then you cannot develop on it without Xcode 7.

However, this is not a completely terrible thing; you can readily have both Xcode 7 and Xcode 6 on the same computer.

(What you *cannot* do, according to Apple, is revert your iPhone back to iOS 8 - but there are some comments below from people who were able to do it.)

Comment: "However, this is not a completely terrible thing; you can readily have both Xcode 7 and Xcode 6 on the same computer." Sure, but if you use a lot of Swift and don't want to upgrade to Swift 2 yet, you effectively can't build on your phone anymore.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Indeed. And my answer is clear about that. But the time to think about that was _before_ installing the new beta onto the phone.

Comment: Agreed, though unless I'm mistaken, Apple nowhere says that updating your phone will then require Xcode 7 to develop for it, even in 100% Objective-C projects.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets I'm sure you're right, but that's why the OP asked the question, no?

Comment: Yeah, true. I guess I just find it weird that it's not possible to use Xcode 6.3 anymore, and that they don't mention that anywhere.

Comment: I managed to revert my device back to iOS 8 without a problem, I'm not sure why Apple says you can't.

Comment: I reverted my device back to iOS8 as well, you have to put your device in DFU mode in order to go back.

Comment: @N7infiltrator I'm going to modify my answer to point out that you and others have been able to revert.

Answer (score 15):

You can RUN App on iOS 9 device using Xcode 6, But firstly **you need to build your app on XCode 7, after that it will support on XCode 6.**
I dont know the reason.
I have checked this on My Mac.

[EDIT]
**Steps**

1. Build the project on Xcode 7 while Xcode 6 is opened on the same
   project.
2. **Disconnect the device and reconnect it**.(Now u can run ur app on XCode6, It may take little time to load device)

When i have checked iOS9 with Xcode6, Bugs are very less.
So i have plan to support iOS9 with XCode6 for quick release.  Later i will do for XCode7.

Comment: I can confirm this actually works. Build the project on Xcode 7 while Xcode 6 is opened on the same project. Disconnect the device and reconnect it. It should work now.

Comment: That should be an accepted answer. Works for me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

You can build to an iOS 9.0 or 9.1 beta device from Xcode 6.4, not out of the box though.
Download Xcode 7.0 and/or Xcode 7.1 beta dmg, and copy the

```
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.0 (13A340)
```

from Xcode 7.0 or:

```
.../9.1 (13B5110e)
```

from Xcode 7.1 beta folders to corresponding folder in your Xcode 6.x.
After restarting Xcode iOS 9.0/9.1 devices will no longer be marked an ineligible.

Comment: This was an easy and reliable work around.   Especially if you had issues building your project with xCode 7 & swift 2.  I'm waiting for some libs to be updated before I go down that track again.

Comment: Great, it is a logical solution, should definitely work and it is working.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest XCode. Keep both versions on your Mac. Give Keep Both when installing the new XCode and do not give Replace present XCode during the installation.

Go to application, right click XCode --> show package contents. Copy the latest version from the path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

and copy to the Xcode you are currently working in the same path. Find the screen shots below and start working.

[image]

[image]

Happy coding.

Comment: Great, it is a logical solution, should definitely work and it is working.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need build your project at Xcode 7.0, just open and select your device, after that, open your Xcode 6.4 and your device will automatically update the necessary things to build app by Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest or correct way. But if you really have to test once or twice in the device.

In Xcode,

1. Product -> Archive
2. Build for Ad-Hoc Distribution
3. Connect the device
4. Open Itunes, Select the device,
5. Select Apps, Drag and drop the .ipa file generated in step 2 to itunes
6. Press install

App will be installed to the ios9 device.

Comment: Great answer.  Simple (as long as you have all the right certificates), and just need a one off build for a simple test.  Saved me hours of work. Knew this already but forgot ... Xcode is a labyrinth sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to download Xcode 7 beta since tools like the compiler and debugger are part of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on Apple Developer Website ([here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)), Xcode 7 Beta has the Swift 2 compiler and SDK for iOS 9.  My guess is, your current Xcode doesn't know how to compile for iOS 9 SDK.

However, Apple doesn't specifically mention Xcode 7 as a requirement.  It states that OS X Yosemite or later is required.

I don't think you can specifically download an SDK that isn't supported inside Xcode.  For example, you can go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and under Components you may see the iOS 9 Simulator.

If you go to the iOS 9 SDK and download it, it seems to only download the device OS and not the entire SDK.

In conclusion, I believe that the SDK "kit" is integrated with Xcode 7 that would allow you to develop on your iOS 9 Device.  Without upgrading, I don't see you being able to do that.  I could be wrong though.